# Conflicting changes to the role x of the relationship y have been detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am having the exception

> Conflicting changes to the role x of the relationship y have been detected.

Every time I add my entity to my context

```
Database.MyEntitys.Add(MyEntity);
```

The class MyEntity contain this property :

```
public virtual ICollection<DetailInfo> Group { get; set; }
```

The DetailInfo class is pretty simple:

```
public class DetailInfo:BaseEntity {
    public virtual Detail Detail { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public virtual MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }
}
```

The DatabaseContext is also simple:

```
public class MyEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity> {
    public MyEntityConfiguration() {
        HasMany(e => e.Group).WithRequired(s => s.MyEntity).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}

public class DetailInfoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DetailInfo> {
    public DetailInfoConfiguration() {
        HasRequired(x => x.MyEntity).WithMany(s => s.Group);
        HasRequired(x => x.Detail);
        HasKey(s => s.ID);
        ToTable("DetailInfo");
    }
}
```

On the Database side the table MyEntity has a primary key to the column ID. The DetailInfo has also a primary key called ID. DetailInfo contains 2 FK, one to MyEntity and one to Detail which is another entity.

In the problematic scenario, the MyEntity is new has a new Detail. I am expecting a new entry for MyEntity with a new Detail and having all FK correctly setup.

#### Edit:

here is the Insert:

```
public virtual int Insert(MyEntity myEntity) {

    if (myEntity.Group != null && myEntity.Group.Count() == 0) {
        myEntity.Group = null; 
    }

    if (myEntity.Group != null) {
        foreach (var g in myEntity.Group)
        {
         if (g.PropertyOneToOne != null) {
                if (g.PropertyOneToOne.ID == 0) {
                    myEntity.PropertyOneToOne = null;
                }
                else {
                    if (!Database.PropertyOneToOnes.Local.Any(e => e.ID == g.PropertyOneToOne.ID)) {
                        Database.PropertyOneToOnes.Attach(g.PropertyOneToOne);
                    }
                    myEntity.PropertyOneToOne = Database.PropertyOneToOnes.Local.Single(e => e.ID == g.PropertyOneToOne.ID);
                }
            }
            else {
                myEntity.PropertyOneToOne = null;
            }
        }
    }
    Database.MyEntitys.Add(myEntity);
}
```

Comment: where are your dbsets declared?

Comment: In my DatabaseContext class that inherit of DbContext.

Comment: Could you show the code that causes the exception? (I'm wondering what it means that "MyEntity has a new Detail" although MyEntity doesn't have a Detail property in the model you are showing.)

Comment: This happens when your object graph is inconsistent - for example entity A has reference to B in navigation property but reverse navigation property on B doesn't contain reference to A. Did you make any changes to the way how EF detects changes?

Comment: I added some of the code where the Insert is done. The only reference that A and B doesn't know each other are with the "PropertyOneToOne" (see the new code). Only the MyEntity knows about it. But, the new code added that make everything fail concern only the addition of the property "Group" this is why I suspect more the "Group" property configuration to be wrong.

Comment: I have try to change `HasRequired(x => x.Detail);` with `HasRequired(x => x.Detail).WithRequiredPrincipal();` without any success. I though that the WithRequiredPrincipal would make the one side of the navigation work but it doesn't look to be.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is this one:

MyEntity has an ID of 0 since it's a new MyEntity.
The Group is also new and contain a reference to MyEntity.

So, `MyEntity` contains a list of Group which contain a reference back to `MyEntity`.

The problem is that `MyEntity.Group.MyEntity` seems to be "new and not the same" as `MyEntity`. When adding MyEntity to the context, it found a conflict.

To solve the problem I set `Group.MyEntity` to NULL and keep the reference of Group inside the list of `MyEntity`. When saving, `MyEntity` reference (ID) is set into the Group table.

I am not sure it's the cleanest way to do it, but the problem is finally solved.

Comment: Doesn't work for me because the Group.MyEntity throws an error when I try to set it null.

Comment: @patrick-desjardins I faced with the same issue and I solved it following the same way you did. Anyway I'm working with EF 6, and I'm not so convinced the suggested solution is still the best one. By chance, have you heard something new about that?

Comment: I setted as null all referenced fields before attach item and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Some other solution might be we need to configure 2 way binding data because MyEntity need Group and Group has MyEntity. You can refer to this link to configure two way binding. Hope it helps. [EF 5.0 Code First Two way navigation withought foreign key id in child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092061/ef-5-0-code-first-two-way-navigation-withought-foreign-key-id-in-child)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be that you are creating a new child list and you are assigning that list to multiple items of the parent list, the solution is that you should create a new child list for each of the parent items.