# EF Code First IDbSet<TEntity>.Attach() Conflicting changes to the role _ of the relationship _ have been detected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have the following code:

```
using (var db = new SourceLogContext())
{
    db.LogEntries.Attach(this);
    db.Entry(this).Collection(c => c.ChangedFiles).Load();
}
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=Conflicting changes to the role 'LogEntry_LogSubscription_Target' of the relationship 'SourceLog.Model.LogEntry_LogSubscription' have been detected.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Attach>b__1()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity)
       at SourceLog.Model.LogEntry.LoadChangedFiles() in C:\github.com\tomhunter-gh\SourceLog\SourceLog.Model\LogEntry.cs:line 62
  InnerException: (empty)
```

The offending line is here: https://github.com/tomhunter-gh/SourceLog/blob/443fb74a37db89522f85b4dfc941c52922785e7a/SourceLog.Model/LogEntry.cs#L62

The LogEntry has it's LogSubscription assigned here: https://github.com/tomhunter-gh/SourceLog/blob/443fb74a37db89522f85b4dfc941c52922785e7a/SourceLog.Model/LogSubscription.cs#L88

It looks like the assignment creates a new LogSubscription instance and assigns it, and then the Attach references a different instance (but with the same Id).  Why does this cause the error and how would I avoid it?

In LogSubscription L88 I'm basically trying to add the LogEntry to the collection property of the LogSubscription but without loading the entire LogEntry collection.  Is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: Is it something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939964/conflicting-changes-to-the-role-x-of-the-relationship-y-have-been-detected)?

Comment: Yes it is like that (at least it's the same error message). I'd already seen that post but unfortunately it didn't help me figure out my problem.  I think what's going on is that the LogEntry is assigned to a LogSubscription instance, and then added to an observable collection which somehow updates the LogSubscription reference to a different instance (the one holdings the collection of LogEntry's), and EF detects this when I try to re-attach the LogEntry..

Comment: Seeing your code, also after your previous question, I again feel that you should rethink your architecture. The purpose of code-first is persistence ignorance. You defeat that purpose by using persistence code (i.e. context) inside an entity object. This is really smelly. I can imagine that it causes all kinds of side effects. For instance: a `LogEntry` object is materialized by a context. The object attaches itself to another context. Is it always detached from its original context at that point? Use view models that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Your classes are far too busy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GertArnold.  I could definitely do with guidance re architecture and patterns.  Do you know of any good articles/books I could take a look at?  I've seen quite a few ASP.NET MVC + EF Code First, but not much combining WPF and EF Code First.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding the error by not attaching the LogEntry entity, and just querying the database for the ChangedFiles collection instead:

```
using (var db = new SourceLogContext())
{
    ChangedFiles = db.LogEntries.Where(x => x.LogEntryId == LogEntryId).Include(x => x.ChangedFiles).Single().ChangedFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually solved this in another situation by overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var logEntry = obj as LogEntry;
    if (logEntry == null)
        return false;
    return LogEntryId.Equals(logEntry.LogEntryId);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return LogEntryId.GetHashCode();
}
```